# Gensim row wise dataframe summary

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, gensim, summarization

I am using 'Gensim' to generate summary of different rows I have. Here is what the original dataframe looks like:

```
df.head()

                                   Example Content
0   Not happy they have just reduced rates for Und...
1   One of the worst banks. I had a very bad exper...
2   Some one in lloyds has signed a form in My nam...
3   Card blocked due to ordering a takeaway from m...
4   There are plenty of better banks than Lloyds.\...
```

I am able to apply summarization to every row using gensim. Problem is, I want every rows summary to appear against its original, and this is not happening. Here is what my code looks like:

```
a = []

for i in df['Example Content']:

    i= i + str(". This is second sentence. This is third")             # this is to add two more sentences so that gensim summarizes it. These sentence add no value to summary.
    a = summarize(i, ratio=0.4, split = True)

df['Summary'] = a
```

And here is the ouput to the above code:

```
                                     Example Content                                 Summary
0   Not happy they have just reduced rates for Und...       Today I got a new phone and switched my sim an...
1   One of the worst banks. I had a very bad exper...       Today I got a new phone and switched my sim an...
2   Some one in lloyds has signed a form in My nam...       Today I got a new phone and switched my sim an...
3   Card blocked due to ordering a takeaway from m...       Today I got a new phone and switched my sim an...
4   There are plenty of better banks than Lloyds.\...       Today I got a new phone and switched my sim an...
```

Below shown are all the individual summaries, generated by gensim, of each row:

```
The 2nd address was a shopping centre and they didnt even give me the name of the business.
I wasn't to know as I through Gallarias Novas was the shop name but that was just the place.
They said that they had issued a new card that I hadn't received and even though they new I was abroad using my card they stopped it anyway.
When my new card did arrive after getting home I now know the reason was that they were making me have a con tactless card whcih I did nto request.

 Today I got a new phone and switched my sim and set up my banking apps inc Halifax and LloydÕs.
Halifax worked fine, usual 4 digit code and confirmation call came through and all set up in mins.
```

How should i grab individual summaries corresponding to the original content and place them in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting your list. Replace

```
a = summarize(i, ratio=0.4, split = True)
```

with

```
a.append(summarize(i, ratio=0.4, split = True))
```